# How to stop functions when leaving the page in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I want to stop the functions when the page will leave.

This is my **tab4.page.ts**:

```
async getUserDetail(){ 
    this.dataexists = false;
    this.userActiveChallanges = [];   
    let me=this;   
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: '',
      // duration: 2200,
      translucent: true,
      spinner: 'crescent',
      showBackdrop: false,
      cssClass: 'my-loading-class'
    });
    await loading.present();  
    this.userActiveChallanges=[];
    this.storage.get('USERPROFILE').then(userObj => { 
      // console.log('User Profile :',userObj);
      me.userprofile = userObj; 
      me.sendFitDatafunction(userObj);
      me.myapi.apiCall('userActiveChallenges/'+userObj.id,'GET','').subscribe((data) => {
        // console.log(data); 
        me.response=data;       
        loading.dismiss();
        if(me.response.status === 'success'){
          if(me.response && me.response.data && me.response.data.length>0){
            this.userActiveChallanges=me.response.data;
            this.flip(this.userActiveChallanges[0].challenge_id);
          }
          this.dataexists = true;
        } else{
          this.userActiveChallanges = '';
          this.dataexists = true;
        }

      }, error => { loading.dismiss(); console.log(error); });

    });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {

  }
```

I want to stop this function when the page will leave because when I am not getting any response nor any error from the api the loader keeps running and when I move to the other page, it is showing there.

So, I want to stop the function when the page will leave.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of local const loading, declare it as a property of your ts class (tab4).

now change your code and assign loader to it:

replace: `const loading`
with:

```
this.loading
```

Now inside ionViewWillLeave call:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
    if (this.loading) { this.loading.dismiss() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know the function to stop your function, but to make something when you leave a page, you make it in IonViewDidLeave()

Comment: Okay, I got it but how to shop that function when the page will leave.